# How to Reassign Input Strip in Blender? (Linux)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, workflow

[image: Effect strip Input 1 is locked]

I want to recycle my already made transform strip but the program wouldn't let me. I can't find any clear help. Using 'Swap input strip'/'Reassign input strip'/... gives me errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow the procedure as outlined in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMSaf24Veao). In summary, you have to duplicate your original strip with its transform strip attached. Then, change the source of the duplicated strip to the one that you want the effect to be copied on.